# Viewing Variables in Spyder's Variable Explorer

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to download data from yahoo and view it in the Spyder IDE "Variable Explorer". However when I create my data variable it does not show up in the variable explorer window.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
all_data = {}
date_start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
date_end = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)

data= web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', date_start, date_end)
```

I followed some others advice but it did not resolve the issue:

1) Go to the options menu of the Variable Explorer (the last icon from top to bottom to its right).

2) Select the option called Show collection contents.

3) Do a right mouse click over the Variable Explorer and select the option called Rezise rows to contents.

Comment: I ve got the same issue, did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it firstly by running the program (on the left) and then in the options menu of the Variable Explorer showing unsupported data (I use Spyder in spanish, so I think is like "Show collection contents").

Spyder 2.3.9
Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Spyder (3.x) you won't see anything in the Variable Explorer unless you are in debug mode.  Sometimes I have to drop out of debug and back in to get new values to show up.  It seems to be a weakness of Spyder.